# compare textbox to database using csharp

Tags: mysql, textbox

Hi guys I just want to compare textbox.text to the database. Here's my code:

```
string str = string.Format("select Firstname,Lastname,Middlename,Extensionname from tblpatient where Firstname ='" + _FirstName.Text + "', Lastname ='" + _LastName.Text + "', Middlename ='" + _MiddleName.Text + "', Extensionname ='" + _ExtensionName.Text + "'");
Modules.Mod.SQL.ExecQuery(str);
if (_FirstName.Text == ("Firstname") || _LastName.Text == ("Lastname") || _MiddleName.Text == ("Middlename") || _ExtensionName.Text == ("Extensionname")) ;
{
    MessageBox.Show("Patient Name is already used", "Page Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    _LastName.Focus();
    _FirstName.Focus();
    _MiddleName.Focus();
    _ExtensionName.Focus();
    return;
}
```

I'm getting an error. But its not working.. please help

Comment: What error you getting ?

Comment: Did my answer get you what you are looking for. If yes, feel free to accept the answer so that it could help others who come across with the same type of doubts in future.

Answer (score 0):

Change the first line to:

```
string str = string.Format("select Firstname,Lastname,Middlename,Extensionname from tblpatient where Firstname ='" + _FirstName.Text + "' AND Lastname ='" + _LastName.Text + "' AND Middlename ='" + _MiddleName.Text + "' AND Extensionname ='" + _ExtensionName.Text + "'");
```

`,` cannot be used in `where` clause. Use `AND` or `OR` instead.

**Side note:** However, I don't recommend this method since it increases SQL injection risks. Use parameterised query.